# Catch and send the Integrity error in the response in Django rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the application I want to catch the Integrity error, format it and send to the user for which I am doing something like this:

```
class ProductUploadAPIView(APIView):
    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request):
        owner = request.user.pk
        d = request.data.copy()
        d['owner'] = owner
        file_obj = request.FILES['document']
        df = pd.read_excel(file_obj)
        df = df.reset_index()

        error_details = []  # List to store error details

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            try:
                product = Product.objects.create(
                    name=row['name'],
                    sku=row['sku'],
                    product_unit_id=row['product_unit_id'],
                    ..... rest of the code
            except IntegrityError as e:
                error_msg = str(e)
                print("error message", error_msg)
                detail = error_msg.split('DETAIL: ')[1]
                error_details.append({'row': index + 2, 'detail': detail})

            except Exception as e:
                error_msg = str(e)
                error_details.append({'row': index + 2, 'detail': error_msg})

        if error_details:
            return Response({'errors': error_details}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return Response("File uploaded successfully")
```

But it doesn't return any response and give the integrity error directly which is not very readable to the user

What changes should be made to send the column and row of the origin of error?